# How to replicate Inbox floating action button (with text for each sub button)?

Tags: java, android, view, android-custom-view, floating-action-button

I was just wondering if anyone has any idea on how to replicate the floating action button view the new Inbox app has for android?
I have the floating action buttons working (with sub buttons) working with a modified version of this library:
https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button/blob/master/README.md

However I am having trouble trying to get the textview next to the button, like in the inbox app.

If someone could offer me a suggestion on how i would go about modifying the library to accommodate this, or any other way of achieving it, i would much appreciate it.

Thanks for your time
Corey

Answer (score 7):

Since Labels FAB feature (like in Evernote or Inbox apps) was added to this awesome [library](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button) feel free to use it:

Gradle dependency:

```
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
```

Layout.xml:

```
     <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/white"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/white_pressed"
        fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/half_black"
        fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
            fab:fab_title="Action A"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
            fab:fab_title="Action B"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/white_pressed"/>

    </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>
```

menu_labels_style.xml:

```
    <style name="menu_labels_style">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/fab_label_background</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

fab_label_background.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/black_semi_transparent"/>
    <padding
        android:left="16dp"
        android:top="4dp"
        android:right="16dp"
        android:bottom="4dp"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

`FloatinActionsMenu` is `ViewGroup` it can accept any view.

Create layout like:

```
<FloatingActionsMenu
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>
<RelativeView
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content">
   <TextView
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/floating_description_1"/>
     <FloatingActionButton
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      //....
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeView
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content">
   <TextView
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/floating_description_2"/>
     <FloatingActionButton
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      //....

</RelativeLayout>
</FloatingActionsMenu>
```

Style `TextView` as your heart desires, backgrounds, text color etc.

Please note that first `FloatingActionButton` will be displaced to the size of child view that has largest width. You should move it to largest child width - first floating button width.

If you want to add `TextView` also to that FloatingAction, get it by id `R.id.fab_expand_menu`, or `.getChildAt(0)`, wrap it programatically as you would do it in xml and set it using `addView(0, wrapped)`

I'm planning to fork, if by any chance I have time to fix it. I'll post a link to the fork.